# How to vary shade of specific table row id

Tags: html, css

I am generating a table using Ruby on Rails. It is easy enough to color odd/even rows differently using css. It is also easy to color rows of a specific id/class a given color. I have the need to shade rows on a table based on id. My question is, how do I alternate the colors of that id, IE: alternate different shades of the same color for a given id?

```
#owner tr:nth-of-type(odd){ background:#eee !important;}
```

CSS of this nature does not work. Is my only solution JS/JQ? Highly prefer pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right you can use rgba to shade the color.

- background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.5); // darker
- background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0); // normal
- background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); // lighter

**css**

```
.table-class {
width: 500px;
font-size: 15px;
}

.table-class td {
width: 25%;
}

#owner tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.2);
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#owner tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.2);
}
```

**html**

```
<table class="table-class" id="owner">
<tr>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
<td>test test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JSFiddle** you can play around with it to see if this is what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4J9s/